# Outputting the total number for a certain category

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is the database I'm using: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArJekOQpal0JFIr1h3NXYcFVngnCNUxg/view?usp=sharing

**For EACH academic, compute the total number of papers s/he has written. Output
should include the acnum and total number of papers for each academic. In particular,
an academic without any papers should have zero(0) as number of papers in the
output. You must use a JOIN operator.**

I'm unsure how to output the total number of papers for each academic.

My attempt at this question:

```
SELECT acnum, panum
FROM author NATURAL JOIN paper;
```

This outputs the panums and acnums, but it doesn't specify the total for each acnum. Is there a keyword to output the total for each acnum?

Thank you.

Comment: use the `GROUP BY` and `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: `left join` plus `group by` and a `coalesce(count(*), 0)` to get the zeros.

Comment: I tried this:
`SELECT acnum, panum, coalesce(count(*), 0)
    FROM author LEFT JOIN paper
    GROUP BY acnum;`
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Of course you need to add a join-condition. And you must join `academic` and `author`, not `paper`

Answer (score 0):

Do a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Then you can count the number of matching author rows. If there is no matching author rows then because of the LEFT JOIN there is a NULL. For a null field when counting specific fields it will count as no row (hence zero).

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', academic.title, academic.initials, academic.faname), COUNT(author.panum)
FROM academic
LEFT OUTER JOIN author
ON academic.acnum = author.acnum
GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(' ', academic.title, academic.initials, academic.faname)
```

Comment: Why the `concat` instead of a simple `group by col1,col2`?

Comment: You can do either (ie, bring back and group by the individual fields, or bring them back and group by them all together). Depends if you want the results output directly.